# how to decode byte array to bitmap without OOM Exception

Tags: java, android, bitmap, out-of-memory, bitmapfactory

I stuck in out of memory. I’m trying to load an image with byte array but what ever i’ve done it wouldn’t work. I get bitmap decoder error I guess. These are all code :

```
       String password = prefs.getString("BookKey", "");
       BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
       buf.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
       buf.close();
       byte[] bytesdecrpy = decrypt(bytes, password);

       BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
       options.inDither = true;
       options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
       options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
       options.inTempStorage = new byte[32 * 1024];
       options.inBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytesdecrpy, 0,
               bytesdecrpy.length, options);

       bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(options.outWidth,
               options.outHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

       imageView.setImage(ImageSource.bitmap(bm));
```

I read as a byte array my encrypt png from device file but **i having problem that when i create bitmap for bitmap variable**. I still couldn’t run as well for 2 days. If anyone can help me to solve this problem it would be great. Thank you.

**EDIT**

I've tried only decode my byte array to bitmap like this but problem never changed i've started get problem in decode then

```
       bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytesdecrpy, 0,
               bytesdecrpy.length, options);
```

Comment: Could you please provide the stack trace as well as the size of your image and where are you running your code from?

Comment: about 100-200kb and android studio if you meant that

Answer (score 0):

This can cause OOM Exception if the bitmap is too large
You could use a background thread to decode and load an image in the container
or use a caching technique as explained in https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html